# React Native: Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: require

Tags: react-native, expo, require

I'm trying to debug my react native project with expo and it recently started giving me this error. For images, I use the require statement [as mentioned on the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images) to import. Now it is causing an exception to my whole project. How can I resolve this?

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

export default function Logo({ goBack }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.logo}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/logo.jpg')} style={styles.image} onClick={goBack} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the exception  details ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import image from '../assets/logo.jpg'
export default function Logo({ goBack }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.logo}>
        <Image source={image} style={styles.image} onClick={goBack} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

try this code

Comment: I tried this and it's still giving the same error. Maybe it's from a different part of code.